# allow overflow of one col into another

Tags: css

I am trying to display the dropdown menu using position absolute, but the div becomes non-clickable.

I have tried using overflow auto, white-space: `nowrap`, z-index: 999, pointer-events none of these worked

I want this dropdown to come as a normal logout menu overlapping on all columns and text.[current state of my dropdown menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSEKB.png)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>pagedemo</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<style>

.dropdown{
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: white;
    width: 8.25rem;
    left: 3rem;
    min-height: 4rem;
    color: gray;
    bottom: 0rem;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.11);
    overflow-x: scroll;
    background-color: yellowgreen;
    padding:10px;
    margin-top: 10rem;
}
.dropdownOption{
    width: 8.25rem;
}
.dropdownOption:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: honeydew;
}

.leftNav{
    background-color: white;
    height: 100vh;
}
</style>

<body style="background-color: bisque;">
        <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-1, leftNav" >
                <div class="dropdown">
                    <div class="dropdownOption">
                        logout
                    </div>
                    <div class="dropdownOption">
                        account settings
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-10" style="background-color: tomato;">
                data
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Add pointer-events: none; and div that is set to absolute comes through clickable.

Comment: Hi. We need a bit of your code if you want help :)

Comment: add to the select `position:relative;z-index:9999;`

Comment: z-index and position: relative; doesn't do anything.

Comment: I have provided my code now

Comment: It seems you haven't provided everything that is relevant to your problem. Run your code here and you'll see. Can you just add the missing bits (and only those!)?

Comment: I've updated it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add a `z-index` on your `.leftNav` component to ensure it's in front of your main col.

Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/azkq2480/